# Android clicking on one ListView item affect other ListView items?

Tags: android, listview

My `ListView` item consists of the following components - `TextView` and then under it there are two `ImageViews` - `like` and `dislike`.

So when I click on either `like` or `dislike` I want to be able to change the `like` or `dislike` `ImageView` from grey to blue.

At the moment when I click on `like` the `like` `ImageView` does change from grey to blue. But not only for the corresponding `ListView` item but for every 3rd item in the list - so if I have 10 items in my list and I click on the `like` of the first item in the list then 4th, 7th and 10th items `like`  `ImageView` change from grey to blue.

In my `post_list_item.xml` in the `root element` of the file I specified the following `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` but it doesn't help either.

My question is - what do I have to do so that when I click on either `like` or `dislike` I would be able to change the `like` or `dislike` `ImageView` from grey to blue without affecting other list items?

Here is my code of the `CursorAdapter`

```
public class PostCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public PostCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String post = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.POST));
        final String liked = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.LIKED));
        String disliked = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.DISLIKED));
        final String post_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.POST_ID));


String userliked = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.USER_LIKED));


        TextView tvPost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPost );
        tvJoke.setText(post);

        TextView tvLikeCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLikeCount);
        tvLikeCount.setText(liked);

        TextView tvDislikesCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDislikeCount);
        tvDislikesCount.setText(disliked);

        final ImageView ivLike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivLike);
// has the user liked it?
int check = Integer.parseInt(userliked);
if(check == 1){
    String uri = "@drawable/like_blue";  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
    Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    ivLike.setImageDrawable(res);
}
        ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String uri = "@drawable/like_blue"; 
                int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
                Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                ivLike.setImageDrawable(res);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state drawables in your drawables/like.xml like this,

like.xml

```
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/like_blue"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/like_grey"/>
```

you can add to your imageview's

```
android:src="@drawable/like"
android:clickable="true"
```

in your adapter,

```
   ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          if(ivLike.isActivated())
               ivLike.setActivated(false);
          else
               ivLike.setActivated(true);
         }
    });
```

for dislike image also you can do the same.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I did just what you said and it still doesn't work.

Comment: it's changing the image or not. is it affecting others items like you said before.

Comment: Yes, it's changing the image, but it still affects other items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a view recycling issue. To learn more, look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works). In your case, the easiest thing to do is to use the view that's passed into your `onClick` method:

```
    ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view;
            String uri = "@drawable/like_blue"; 
            int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
            Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            icon.setImageDrawable(res);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I did just what you said and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read up on view recycling? Just look at the link, and you'll be able to figure it out.